# Incomplete Gamma function as Meijer G

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, special-functions

How can I write the incomplete Gamma function in terms of the Meijer-G function? Assume that the Incomplete Gamma is given as:

[image]

where alpha, beta and m are real positive constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are several relationships between the incomplete Gamma function and particular Meijer-G functions. For example this one : http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/26/02/01/0002/MainEq1.L.gif

Is it that you want ?

Comment: Yes...thank you a lot :)